How can we modify a function/styings imported via cdn dynamically in reactJs
I am using simplePdf to show pdfs via mobile browsers. Now the component i used for this comes with other features too like downloading etc. I want to hide/remove that parts while displaying the pdf on my site. How can i do that in React ?
This is the sample code (simplified) -
import { EmbedPDF } from "@simplepdf/react-embed-pdf";
....
<div ref={embedRef}>
        <EmbedPDF
          mode="inline"
          style={{ width: '100%', height: '100vh' }}
          documentURL={pdfUrl}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
...

